# Firefox executing onload after element is already loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have an iframe (bad I know) with a load event being set on document ready:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var executeLoad = false;
    $("#ExampleFrame").on("load", function(){
        if(executeLoad){
            doSomething();
        }
    });
    executeLoad = true;
});
</script>

<iframe id="ExampleFrame" name="example"></iframe>
<form id="Example Form" method="post" action="http://externalurl" target="example">
</form>
```

I noticed that `doSomething()` was being executed as soon as the page loaded, so I added the `executeLoad` check, which still has not worked. I have also tried placing the script block into the body below the `form` tag and it is still being executed. This only occurs in Firefox. Is there any way I can ignore the initial load event for `#ExampleFrame`? I would have thought that binding the load events on document ready would have prevented this from occuring.

Comment: The document being ready is no guarantee that external resources like iFrames are completely loaded, it's just a handler for when all the elements are present, and the `</body>` tag has been outputted etc. Images, frames, scripts and other things can still be loading.

Comment: If you want to ignore the first iframe load event, you could probably do something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/rm520834/

Comment: You can inspect `this.contentWindow.location` in the load handler and determine what to do based on that data. Firefox triggers the load handler for "about:blank" at first since the iframe did indeed load on your page, albeit with blank content.

Comment: @adeneo Does this actually prevent the initial execution? The jQuery documentation suggests that it will execute the first instance of the "load" trigger and then never fire again.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage loads(and onload event is triggered) even though other elements like an async call, promise, image loading, iframe loading is still in process. Which means, the HTML document loads even if some Div's and elements are still yet to load.

So, basically if you want the whole webpage & iframe to be fully loaded, use something like this-

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#ExampleFrame").one("load", function(){
        $(this).on("load", doSomething);
    });
});
</script>
<iframe id="ExampleFrame" name="example"></iframe>
<form id="Example Form" method="post" action="http://externalurl" target="example">
</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: And now you have one event handler that creates a new event handler everytime the iFrame loads, creating lots of event handlers, and issues.

Comment: @adeneo Yes. Agreed. But, for his problem, this is a viable solution is what I felt. And, jokulmorder If there is a way in which you can solve the problem by letting the iframe load later, then, don't change the flow. As adeneo said, the page will let slower(loading). Event Handlers everywhere! That'll mess up things.

Comment: The first call should be `.one` instead of `.on`

Comment: Yes. Made changes @csum